# Does $(\neg P)\land Q\equiv P\vee (\neg Q)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $$(\neg P)\land Q\equiv P\vee (\neg Q)$$

On the one hand we can take $$P\vee (\neg Q)=P\vee (\neg\neg Q)=P\vee (\neg Q)=\neg(P\vee (\neg Q))=(\neg P)\land Q$$

On the other hand if $P=True$ and $Q=True$

then $(\neg P)\land Q$ is False and $P\vee (\neg Q)$ is True

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that negation does not change the truth value of the sentence or sub sentence in which it applies. It is the opposite, in fact.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Have you tried to use truth tables? Try that for each of the steps in your "proof" and you'll see where it fails (it has multiple flaws).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

> $$P\lor (\neg Q)=P\lor (\neg \neg Q)$$

which is clearly false (since $\neg Q\neq \neg\neg Q$).

$\neg\neg Q$ is, in fact, the same as $Q$, which is the exact opposite of $\neg Q$.

---

You also wrote

> $$P\vee (\neg Q)=\neg(P\vee (\neg Q))$$

which is also false (in fact, the left side is the **negation** of the right, so the left is true if and only if the right is false).

Answer (score 1):

I usually just make a tautology for such questions -it is a no-brainer test where you insert all possible combinations of truth-values of your sentence. In the following let $T$ abbreviate true, and $F$ abbreviate false.
The combinations we are seeking to test out are
$\begin{array}{lll}
P & Q & \\
T & T & \text{Both are true}\\
T & F & P\text{ is true and }Q \text{ is false}\\
F & T & P\text{ is false and }Q \text{ is true}\\
F & F & \text{Both are false}\\
\end{array}$

You start by filling in the values for the variables ($P$ and $Q$) and then work you way out through every subexpression using the previous results for the sub-expressions (e.g. for step 2 you evaluate negation of $P$ and $Q$, respectively). 
Note that we do all the different combinations at once (one per row). I've indicated the "way out" by the numbering (start with all 1's, then all 2's, etc.). The deeper the expression, the more steps and with more (different) variables, there will be more rows. The previous results I'm using is indicated in bold-face, and I write the result for a sub-expression below the outer-most part of the expression (e.g. the result for $\neg P$ will be occur below the '$\neg$'). The answer whether the sides are equivalent will appear beneath the '$\equiv$' -if it show true, here $T$, for all combinations, then the expressions are equivalent, if not (e.g. if one of the combinations gives $F$), they are not.

**step 1:** (fill in the values)
$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
   2  & 1 &   3  & 1 &    4  & 1&  3   &   2  & 1 \\
(\neg &P)& \land & Q &\equiv& P& \lor & (\neg &Q) \\
      &T &       & T &      & T &     &       & T \\
      &T &       & F &      & T &     &       & F \\
      &F &       & T &      & F &     &       & T \\
      &F &       & F &      & F &     &       & F \\
 \end{array}$

**step 2:**
$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
   2  & 1 &   3  & 1 &    4  & 1&  3   &   2  & 1 \\
(\neg &P)& \land & Q &\equiv& P& \lor & (\neg &Q) \\
   F  &\bf T &       & T &      & T &     &    F  &\bf  T \\
   F  &\bf T &       & F &      & T &     &    T  & \bf F \\
   T  &\bf F &       & T &      & F &     &    F  & \bf T \\
   T  &\bf F &       & F &      & F &     &    T  & \bf F \\
 \end{array}$

**step 3:**
$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
   2  & 1 &   3  & 1 &    4  & 1&  3   &   2  & 1 \\
(\neg &P)& \land & Q &\equiv& P& \lor & (\neg &Q) \\
  \bf F  &T &    F  & \bf T &    & \bf T &  T   &  \bf F  & T \\
  \bf  F  &T &    F  & \bf F &       & \bf T &  T   &  \bf T  & F \\
  \bf  T  &F &    T  & \bf T &       & \bf F &  F   &  \bf F  & T \\
  \bf  T  &F &    F  & \bf F &       & \bf F &  T   &  \bf T  & F \\
 \end{array}$

**step 4:**
$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
   2  & 1 &       3  & 1 &    4  & 1&  3   &   2  & 1 \\
(\neg &P)& \land & Q &\equiv& P& \lor & (\neg &Q) \\
   F  &T &   \bf  F  & T & \underline{F}    & T & \bf  T   &    F  & T \\
   F  &T &   \bf  F  & F &  \underline{F}    & T & \bf  T   &    T  & F \\
   T  &F &   \bf  T  & T &  \underline{F}    & F & \bf  F   &    F  & T \\
   T  &F &   \bf  F  & F &  \underline{F}    & F & \bf  T   &    T  & F \\
 \end{array}$

So nope, the two sides are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that if $P$ and $Q$ are true, then the statement does not hold for precisely the reasons you describe. This means that $(\lnot P)\land Q$ is not equivalent to $P\lor (\lnot Q)$.

Your first mistake is $P\lor (\lnot Q)=P\lor (\lnot\lnot Q)$.